# 2 Windows bootable partitions

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu 13.10 alongside windows 7 on my laptop and now I have two bootable windows partitions sda1 and sda2. There is a third partition for windows sda3 as recovery.
is this normal after installing a second operating system?

Comment: Recovery partition would be created by your system manufacturer while during the first OS installation.

Comment: Don't worry this is completely normal. I have this too. :)

Comment: Close-voters: It seems to me that this question is clear (and on-topic)--it's asking, *does installing Ubuntu alongside Windows cause there to be two bootable Windows partitions, and is it a problem?* @AvinashRaj You might want too post that as an answer. It covers the same ground as [robysottini's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/438732/22949) but the way you explain it is somewhat different and I think may be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal. If you ever want to format your laptop, you can enter that third partition. It is the best way to give format to your laptop because this process include all drivers that your Windows needs. Have in mind that recovery means erase everything of your hard drive. Before doing that back your files up.